# How to keep my place when two column become three columns

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, user-experience

I have a new project using a bootstrap two-column layout, nav and content. Users will want to drill-down on blocks in the content. Sometimes it'll be two-column cards and sometimes it'll be tables. Clicking anywhere on an item should drill down.

When I click on the card, I want a drawer to slide out from the right side of the screen with the details. But there isn't enough room. So I want to shrink the nav and second column. The second column will became only one card wide, leaving room for details to appear in a new third column.

Here's a working example without animation. It's jarring but it gets the point across. Click on a recipe and you'll see it change states. Click again to remove the "drill down" panel.

https://jsfiddle.net/cg5n2eL6/

Question: How do I keep the current recipe where it is? That's a huge user experience issue. If you use card 1, it's fine. But any recipe in column 2 or even some later on in column one and it jumps somewhere else.

If it matters I'm sure I'll end up dumping the `.col-sm-6` classes ... it looks like in order to get the transition between states to be animated, I need to use .main-content.main-content-full-width or something like that and just toggle main-content-full-width, instead of toggling both .col-sm-6 and .col-sm-4. So if that affects your answer, you have been warned. :)

Comment: You need to drop `position: fixed`, since it is relative to the viewport. `position: absolute` might be what you need

Comment: After some feedback from some friends, I just wanted to reiterate that my only goal is to keep the recipe where it is (at least vertically, it would have to shift left if it was in the second column.)